# Cannot run package installed with npm -g

Tags: ubuntu, npm

on my Ubuntu machine, I install packages using "npm install -g SomePackage" 
the installation process finishes correctly but when I try to run the new package from the CLI i get SomePacjage is not a defined command.

I assume that Ubuntu cannot find the installed package.

Any ideas?

Comment: What package are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

More details required to troubleshoot but you can try with sudo

```
sudo npm install -g SomePackage
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to depend on the package from your own module using something like Node.js' require, then you want to install locally, which is npm install's default behavior.

`sudo npm install <some_package> //install it locally`

Or if there is any permission issues try commands
`sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm`
`sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config`